# Cordova push notification service not working in IOS device

Tags: ios, plugins, ionic-framework, push, cordova-plugins

i am wondering why cordova push plugin is not working in IOS device.IOS ver 9.3

I am using ionic push services.

```
Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Version: 1.2.4
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.6 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v5.9.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3 Build version 7D175
```

It works on emulator and web but not in the device. It throws me this error

```
2016-04-11 04:51:52.385 example[1304:814527] Ionic Core: plugins are ready
2016-04-11 04:51:52.386 example[1304:814527] WARN: hideKeyboardAccessoryBar has been removed until a method is found that doesn't get rejected from the App Store.
2016-04-11 04:51:52.386 example[1304:814527] Ionic Push: register
2016-04-11 04:51:52.386 example[1304:814527] ERROR: Ionic Push (dev): error connecting development push service.
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Any luck yet?

Comment: yes it got solved as i disabled development push and restarted xcode and build again.

Comment: same here. and also `ionic-platform-web-client` plugin had not installed properly. I had to install it manually with `bower install --save-dev ionic-platform-web-client`

Comment: yes i had to do that as well